# Jquery color pallete exctraction from url/website?

Tags: jquery, colors, web

Is there some jquery plugin or tool that enables you to extract pallete of (for example) three colors or its HEX/RGB values from websites according to url you've entered?

I'm trying to include something like that on my webpage but I google it and did not find something like that, only similar pages that do so.

For example this is perfect example of what I'm searching to: http://www.colorcombos.com/grabcolors.html

I suppose that there is something more behind of that beside jquery...

idea?

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a server side approach, e.g. loading a page/stylesheet with PHP and then analyzing its contents.